# Open current live wallpaper settings from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, settings, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I'm working on an Android live wallpaper. I have everything working just fine so far, but I need to be able to open the wallpaper settings (that already work in the wallpaper preview) from an activity.

Is there an intent or anything that will put the user on the preview screen for the current wallpaper, or just open the settings activity directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get to the preview directly, but you can get to the live wallpaper chooser:

```
startActivity(new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER));
```

Otherwise, just start your settings activity directly.

Edit: Just found this but didn't try (It's 3.0 an up):

```
startActivity(new Intent(WallpaperManager.WALLPAPER_PREVIEW_META_DATA));
```

Comment: I came to the solution of opening the settings directly.  Now I just need to look at how to get the active live wallpaper.

Comment: WallpaperManager is your friend, WallpaperManager.getInstance().getWallpaperInfo()

Comment: Jay, thanks again - this (now) does exactly what I needed.  I just needed the check for current wallpaper and you answered the question perfectly. Kudos.

Comment: Thanks Jay .perfect solution what i am looking for. Can u tell me how can i set my current activity as live wallpaper.